# Is it possible to use ng-if with a service value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have the following service that holds some random data

```
.service('dataSrvc', [function() {
    var accountData = {
        accounts: [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'title': 'Account A',
                'selected': true
            },
...
```

When displaying this data in a list, I want to add an icon if lets say the  id for this item equals to 1.

I tried using ng-if

```
<md-icon aria-label="Duplicates Window" md-font-set="material-icons" ng-if="account.id==1">panorama_fish_eye</md-icon>
```

But the icon was never displayed. Trying various things I either make he icon display for each list item or none.

How can I fix this, and display the icon only where needed.

**EDIT**

I am sorry for the partial info.

This is how I create my list

```
<md-sidenav class="site-sidenav md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2"
                md-component-id="left"
                md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" flex>
        <md-list ng-controller="listCtrl" class="listControls">

            <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Possible Duplicate Accounts</md-subheader>
            <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">
                <md-checkbox ng-checked="item.selected" ng-click="toggle(item)"></md-checkbox>
                <p>{{item.title}}</p>
                <md-icon class="md-secondary" ng-click="doSecondaryAction(item.title, $event)" aria-label="Duplicates Window" md-font-set="material-icons">account_circle</md-icon>
                <div flex>
                <md-icon aria-label="Duplicates Window" md-font-set="material-icons" ng-if="account.id==1">panorama_fish_eye</md-icon>
                </div>
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>
```

And this is my controller

```
.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataSrvc', '$mdDialog', function($scope, dataSrvc, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.items = dataSrvc.accounts;

    $scope.exists = function(item) {
        return $scope.items.indexOf(item) > -1;
    };

    $scope.toggle = function(item) {
        item.selected = !item.selected;
    };

    $scope.doSecondaryAction = function(item, event) {
        $mdDialog.show(
            $mdDialog.alert()
                .title('Data Preview')
                .content('Data for ' + item)
                .ariaLabel('Duplicates Window')
            .ok('Done')
            .targetEvent(event)
        );
    };
}])
```

Comment: Why not simply add the icon name in the array?

Comment: It should work. Can you post controller code also? and are you using ngRepeat or some thing?

Comment: Can you post your controller code? Then I can give you more specific help.

Comment: why you are writing/using "account.id"? it should be "item.id" if im not wrong

Comment: You are correct of curse, I was not careful while typing.

Comment: Your edit reveals the real problem - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view, you can only reference values of the controller's scope. (i.e. when you write `ng-if="account.id===1"`, it will be matched against the value of `$scope.account`)

Thus, if you want to display a service value in the view, you have to put it on the $scope inside the controller. (If you want this data to be bound live, you should use a watch expression in the controller, watching the service value)

Matthew Berg's answer (about binding the service itself to the scope) is better performance-wise (there's no need to spend resources to duplicate values) - but this seems to be already what you're doing, see my edit below.

---

*Edit after question edit:*

It seems like your problem is more simple: your ng-repeat runs for every `item in items`, but in the ng-if you're referencing `account` (which is the name for the same thing in the service, but not inside the ng-repeat!)

Just change the ng-if to:

```
ng-if="item.id==1"
```

Answer (score 2):

First in your controller bind the service to the $scope:

```
function($scope, dataSrvc){
    $scope.dataSrvc = dataSrvc
}
```

And then in the dom make reference to that:

```
<md-icon aria-label="Duplicates Window" md-font-set="material-icons" ng-if="dataSrvc.account.id==1">panorama_fish_eye</md-icon>
```

Comment: Maybe my edit helps a bit, because I think I have done what you are suggesting.